# цена Recaptcha v3

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

Вопрос: Что будет делать recaptcha v3 после того как количество бесплатных запросов 1000000/месяц закончатся? Цена на сайте только про другую версию. Кейс: 1000001 запрос- как поведет себя система? Счет потом прилетит просто? Или сообщит об этом( что уже берет деньги)? Или перестанет работать?  Прошу указать цену на запросы. Спасибо. Есть ли информация по отказоустойчивости системы?

Comment: Ввожу в гугле `recaptcha v3 price` и первая ссылка на https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/pricing и там написано про `1$ per 1,000 calls` за `1,000,001 to 10,000,000 calls per month`

Comment: Это другая версия recaptcha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Согласно ответу из FAQ](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#are-there-any-qps-or-daily-limits-on-my-use-of-recaptcha):

> If you wish to make more than 1000 calls per second or 1000000 calls
> per month, you must use reCAPTCHA Enterprise or fill out this form and
> wait for an exception approval. If a site key exceeds 1000 QPS, then
> some requests may not be processed. If a v3 site key exceeds its
> monthly quota, then site_verify may fail open by returning a static
> score 0.9 and an error message `"Over free quota."` for the remainder
> of the month. There are no user-visible indications when v3 sites are
> over quota. If a v2 site key exceeds its monthly quota, then the
> following or a similar message may be displayed to users in the
> reCAPTCHA widget for the remainder of the month: `This site is exceeding reCAPTCHA quota.` Before quota is enforced, site owners will
> be notified by email three times and given at least 90 days to migrate
> to reCAPTCHA Enterprise. Site keys are considered over quota if more
> than 1000000 calls per month are used for any domain. This includes if
> this volume is spread across multiple keys on the same domain.

Т.е. если нужно больше 1000 запросов в секунду или 1000000 за месяц, то нужно использовать версию enterprise (у которой ценник `1$ per 1,000 calls` начинается при 1,000,001 до 10,000,000 запросов за месяц, а превышение оговаривается).

Если запросов больше 1000 в секунду, некоторые запросы могут быть не обработаны (как понимаю, это для бесплатной версии)

При превышении, до конца месяца, для бесплатной версии запрос будет уходить, но результат будет отличаться в зависимости от версии:

- **v3**. Будет возвращаться значение score 0.9 (у score диапазон от 0.0 до 1.0, от худшего к лучшему) и текст ошибки `"Over free quota."`. Причем, пользователь не будет видеть, что на сайте достигнут лимит запросов
- **v2**. На виджете будет отображаться сообщение вида `"This site is exceeding reCAPTCHA quota."`

И в конце указано, что перед тем как квота на запросы закончится, владельцы сайтов получат сообщения на почты